# Buffering a line with varying distances associated with directional quadrant by QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, buffer, bearing

I would like to buffer a set of lines with different distances to the NW, SW, SE, and NE. I have the distances stored in four attribute fields that correspond to the direction the buffer should be applied in. I have reviewed the two posts [How to buffer a line with different distances for left/right sides](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32973/how-to-buffer-a-line-with-different-distances-for-left-right-sides) and [QGIS buffer polygon with different widths on each side](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133986/qgis-buffer-polygon-with-different-widths-on-each-side?rq=1) but they do not fully address my issue. My lines do not flow East to West or North to South so the right/left side buffer option does not offer a solution.

Edit:I have attached a rough rendering of what I would like the output to be. The edges should be smooth.

[image]

Comment: Buffering a point in differing amounts by direction is pretty easy (and already solved). Buffering a *line*, well, I think you're on your own.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188139/buffering-point-with-different-distance-toward-n-e-s-w-using-arcgis-for-deskt

Comment: That looks close. I only have access to open source GIS right now and am not proficient in Python. Should that script be easily transferred to QGIS Python console?

Comment: That's the rub, really, because I certainly wouldn't want to code the next bit, of making a polygon from a line, and that algorithm isn't integrated into *any* GIS package. It would probably take me 2-3 more days of coding, if I didnt get tangled in topology issues (for reference, I've been a full-time GIS software engineer for 29 years; your time effort may vary).

Comment: A graphic of your input and desired output might be helpful so we fully  understand your question.

Comment: Vince, do you have a link to the solution for buffering points in this way?

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt by the Geometry generator; lacks nice smooth corners in your drawing, though.

```
convex_hull(
  make_line(
    project(start_point($geometry), 70, radians(45)),
    project(start_point($geometry), 20, radians(135)),
    project(start_point($geometry), 15, radians(225)),
    project(start_point($geometry), 50, radians(315)),
    project(  end_point($geometry), 70, radians(45)),
    project(  end_point($geometry), 20, radians(135)),
    project(  end_point($geometry), 15, radians(225)),
    project(  end_point($geometry), 50, radians(315))
  )
)
```

[image]

Second attempt: I am afraid below example is probably a dirty trick... debuffer and buffer by 5 meters...

```
buffer(
  buffer(
    convex_hull(
      make_line(
        project(start_point($geometry), 70, radians(45)),
        project(start_point($geometry), 20, radians(135)),
        project(start_point($geometry), 15, radians(225)),
        project(start_point($geometry), 50, radians(315)),
        project(  end_point($geometry), 70, radians(45)),
        project(  end_point($geometry), 20, radians(135)),
        project(  end_point($geometry), 15, radians(225)),
        project(  end_point($geometry), 50, radians(315))
     )
), -5), 5)
```

[image]